# Create module My product/list of user drupal commerce

Tags: commerce, hooks

I'm trying to determine if a user have product any of them, loading all the user products related and node title and body and antoher fields...
Anyone know if such a function exists, or if there's a more elegant method to get this data?
My module code is here ...

```
<?php
    /**
    /**
    * Implements hook_menu().
    */
    function my_product_bijan_menu() {
    $items = array();

    $items['my_module/hello_world'] = array(
    'title' => 'List my Products',
    'page callback' => 'my_products_fnc',
    'access arguments' => array('access content'),
    'type' => MENU_CALLBACK,
    );

    return $items;
    }



    function my_products_fnc() {

    $ordered = FALSE;

    $node_wrapper = entity_metadata_wrapper('node', $node);
    $product_ids = array();
    foreach ($node_wrapper->field_products as $product) {
    $product_ids[] = $product->product_id->value();
    }

    // Query order details for products
    // Note this is the line item product reference table
    $query = db_select('field_data_commerce_product', 'p');
    // Example if you want more fields, but would need to change ->fetchCol()
    // $query->fields('o', array('order_id', 'order_number', 'uid', 'mail'));
    $query->fields('o', array('uid'));
    $query->innerJoin('field_data_commerce_line_items', 'l', 'l.commerce_line_items_line_item_id = p.entity_id');
    $query->innerJoin('commerce_order', 'o', 'o.order_id = l.entity_id');
    $query->condition('p.commerce_product_product_id', $product_ids, 'IN');
    $query->groupBy('o.order_id');
    // Fetch array of uids
    $result = $query->execute()->fetchCol();

    // Check if account->uid in array of order uids
    // If so, uid has ordered product.
    if(in_array($account->uid, $result)){
    $ordered = TRUE;
    }

}
```

And error is :

```
    Notice: Undefined variable: node in my_products_fnc() (line 25 of /home/admin/domains/site.com/public_html/sites/all/modules/my_product_bijan/my_product_bijan.module).
    EntityMetadataWrapperException: Unknown data property field_products. in EntityStructureWrapper->getPropertyInfo() (line 354 of /home/admin/domains/site.com/public_html/sites/all/modules/entity/includes/entity.wrapper.inc).
```

Answer (score 0):

My query is there but i dont know why not work !

```
global $user;
$query = db_select('{node}', 'node');
$query->fields('node', array('nid', 'changed', 'created', 'title', 'status'));
$query->fields('users_node', array('uid', 'mail'));
$query->fields('commerce_node_checkout_node_node', array('line_item_id', 'changed'));
$query->fields('node_counter', array('totalcount'));
$query->leftJoin('{users}', 'users_node', 'node.uid = users_node.uid');
$query->leftJoin('{field_data_commerce_node_checkout_node}', 'field_data_commerce_node_checkout_node', 'node.nid = field_data_commerce_node_checkout_node.commerce_node_checkout_node_target_id AND (field_data_commerce_node_checkout_node.entity_type = 'commerce_line_item' AND field_data_commerce_node_checkout_node.deleted = '0')');
$query->leftJoin('{commerce_line_item}', 'commerce_node_checkout_node_node', 'field_data_commerce_node_checkout_node.entity_id = commerce_node_checkout_node_node.line_item_id');
$query->leftJoin('{node_counter}', 'node_counter', 'node.nid = node_counter.nid');
$query->innerJoin('{node_comment_statistics}', 'node_comment_statistics', 'node.nid = node_comment_statistics.nid');
$query->condition('node.uid', $user->uid);
$query->condition('node.type', array(myitem), 'IN');
$result = $query->execute();
```